# Hide text from blog summary

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

Is there a way to hide a sentence from the blog summary/excerpt on the page which lists all blog posts?

For example, can I create a shortcode that I put around the first sentence of the article, so the first sentence shows up in the actual article, but not the excerpt?

These are the two areas: 
 1. The blog page (I want the text to display as normal) 
 2. The blog listing page. This page displays 10 posts at a time with a
    small excerpt from each post. (I want to hide a portion of the text
    using a shortcode or something similar)

Comment: I do not understand wordpress, but try: <p style="display:none;">Your Text</p>

Comment: So, there are two different things here.

1. The blog page (I want the text to display as normal)
2. The blog listing page. This page displays 10 posts at a time with a small excerpt from each post. (I want to hide a portion of the text using a shortcode or something similar). I think that will hide the text from both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to differentiate texts by adding an ID or a CLASS to them:

1- To display the text you can usually use `<p id="show-text"> Your Text </ p>` and add the custom css `#show-text{display:inline;}`

2 - To hide it `<p id="hidden-text">Your Text</p>` and the custom css: `#hidden-text{display:none;}`

To add a custom css in wordpress, see this link: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. I have the same problem in Blogger. I want some navigation links to be at the top of my blog article, but I don't want this to appear in the article excerpt; I want the actual article content to appear in the excerpt. Defining text as hidden or inline won't matter to the blogger code, it will get treated the same regardless of the context in which it appears.